# Can't connect Tor Network, failed to establish network no bridge work

Tags: bridge

Sorry but i am new  and i have same problem with similar post 
Not work any bridge

```
7/14/2016 10:17:32 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/14/2016 10:17:32 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/14/2016 10:17:32 AM.400 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/14/2016 10:17:32 AM.400 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/14/2016 10:17:33 AM.200 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
7/14/2016 10:17:33 AM.300 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
7/14/2016 10:17:33 AM.400 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 15%: Establishing an encrypted directory connection 
7/14/2016 10:17:33 AM.500 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 20%: Asking for networkstatus consensus 
7/14/2016 10:17:33 AM.600 [WARN] Received http status code 404 ("Not found") from server 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443' while fetching "/tor/keys/fp/REDACTED". 
7/14/2016 10:17:33 AM.600 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 25%: Loading networkstatus consensus 
7/14/2016 10:17:37 AM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/14/2016 10:17:37 AM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
7/14/2016 10:17:37 AM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
7/14/2016 10:17:37 AM.200 [NOTICE] Delaying directory fetches: DisableNetwork is set.
```

Comment: There are no real errors here and you only gave it a few seconds. Why do you think it isn't connecting?

Comment: two day before tor work. hes block and when i restart not work   I try many time and many location i off firewall and antivir

Comment: There's nothing in that log that says anything is wrong.